# Using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula to estimate the exponential of the commutator of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Suppose I have two matrices $e^{H_1t/n},e^{H_2t/n}$ for $t$ a small integer, and $n$ some positive integer, and $H_1,H_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$. I have given in a paper that by using the second order of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula it is true that :

$e^{[H_1,H_2]t + O(t^2/n^2)} = (e^{H_1t/n}e^{H_2t/n}e^{-H_1t/n}e^{-H_2t/n})^{n^2/t}$ where $[A,B]$ is the matrix commutator.

The author then states that $(e^{H_1t/n}e^{H_2t/n}e^{-H_1t/n}e^{-H_2t/n})(e^{-H_1t/n}e^{-H_2t/n}e^{H_1t/n}e^{H_2t/n}) = e^{2[H_1,H_2]t^2/n^2 + O((t/n)^4)}$.

I'm not sure how the author arrived at this last equality. Insights appreciated.

Comment: You've clearly messed up the subscripts 1 and 2. Could you write down your intended expressions, your flow of logic, and what you understand as the [CBH expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula) you are using?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have the first equation as a given, and am trying to see why the second equation holds. I corrected the subscripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost certainly misreading the paper to reverse the flow of logic involved.

You simply evaluate the lowest order CBH expansion mindful of the omitted orders,
$$e^{H_1t/n}e^{H_2t/n}= e^{(H_1+H_2)(t/n) +\frac{1}{2} [H_1,H_2](t/n)^2 + O((t/n)^3)}   \\
      e^{-H_1t/n}e^{-H_2t/n}=  e^{-(H_1+H_2)(t/n) +\frac{1}{2} [H_1,H_2](t/n)^2 + O((t/n)^3)} \\ 
f(t)\equiv (e^{H_1t/n}e^{H_2t/n}e^{-H_1t/n}e^{-H_2t/n})=
  e^{[H_1,H_2](t/n)^2 + O((t/n)^3)}.$$
(Observe the $O(t/n)$ terms mutually commute, being opposite, so they do not contribute to  $O((t/n)^2)$.)

It is then evident that 
$$
f(t) f(-t)= e^{2[H_1,H_2]t^2/n^2 + O((t/n)^4)}, 
$$
since the $O((t/n)^3$ odd terms cancel each other in the sum, leaving  $O((t/n)^4$.

I'm not sure how you concluded your mystery author needed the first equation to derive this.

(Note, instead, that
$
f(t)^m= e^{m[H_1,H_2](t/n)^2 + O((t/n)^3)}
$, but glibly taking $m=n^2/t$ will net an ill-defined error. I suspect there is essential information in your text you omitted.)

Comment: Sorry but how did you get that expression for $f(t)$. Are you simply adding the terms that are being exponentiated? Can't you do that only if both sides commute?

Comment: Adding the exponents and accounting for *all other terms* in the big O remainder! The commutator of the leading term with itself vanishes.